# Stopping a runaway process using C-c C-c

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When i evaluate some source code blocks using C-c C-c sometimes i might have an error and the system hangs on me . The only way to exit at this point is by quitting emacs. Are there any solutions to this. A simple example using R would be

```
#+Begin_src R
print ("testing this command"
#+end_src
```

if I run a C-c C-c in the current *R* session it is waiting for me to complete the braces and therefore emacs hangs as it show 'executing R code block ... ' in the mini buffer.

I understand this is mainly user error, but i would like to not have to interactively test every bit of code and also be able to break out of this as opposed to restarting.
Any help/ insight will be much appreciated
Cheers
Ashok

Comment: Does `C-g` work in this case? It might let you continue interact with emacs regardless of what happens with the R session. [Quitting and Aborting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quitting.html)

Comment: Great this does work

Comment: Under MS Windows, I found no other solution than killing the launched process manually inside the Task Manager.